# MongoDB: adding sort() to query ruins result set for $and query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting

I've stumbled upon some very strange behavior with MongoDB. For my test case, I have an MongoDB collection with 9 documents. All documents have the exact same structure, including the fields `expired_at: Date` and `location: [lng, lat]`.

I now need to find all documents that are not expired yet and are within a bounding box; I show match documents on map. for this I set up the following queries:

```
var qExpiry = {"expired_at": { $gt : new Date() } };
var qLocation = { "location" : { $geoWithin : { $box : [ [ 123.8766, 8.3269 ] , [ 122.8122, 8.24974 ] ] } } };
var qFull = { $and: [ qExpiry, qLocation ] };
```

Since the expiry date is long in the past, and when I set the bounding box large enough, the following queries give me all 9 documents as expected:

```
db.docs.find(qExpiry);
db.docs.find(qLocation);
db.docs.find(qFull);
db.docs.find(qExpiry).sort({"created_at" : -1});
db.docs.find(qLocation).sort({"created_at" : -1});
```

Now here's the deal: The following query returns 0 documents:

```
db.docs.find(qFull).sort({"created_at" : -1});
```

Just adding sort to the AND query ruins the result (please note that I want to sort since I also have a limit in order to avoid cluttering the map on larger scales). Sorting by other fields yield the same empty result. What's going on here?

(Actually even stranger: When I zoom into my map, I sometimes get results for `qFull`, even with sorting. One could argue that `qLocation` is faulty. But when I only use `qLocation`, the results are always correct. And `qExpiry` is always true for all documents anyway)

Comment: Have you tried running the same query using the aggregation framework's `$match` and `$sort` pipelines?

Comment: @chridam -- wow, that did the trick! I will provide an answer since this seems something others might encounter as well. Any idea why this way worked and my initial approach not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try running the same query using the aggregation framework's **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** and **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipelines:

```
db.docs.aggregate([
    { "$match": qFull },
    { "$sort": { "created_at": -1 } }
]);
```

or implicitly using **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** by specifiying a comma-separated list of expressions as in

```
db.docs.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "expired_at": { "$gt" : new Date() },
            "location" : { 
                "$geoWithin" : { 
                    "$box" : [ 
                        [ 123.8766, 8.3269 ], 
                        [ 122.8122, 8.24974 ] 
                    ] 
                } 
            }
        } 
    },
    { "$sort": { "created_at": -1 } }
]);
```

Not really sure why that fails with `find()`

Answer (score 1):

chridam suggestion using the aggregation framework of MongoDB proved to be the way to go. My working query now looks like this:

```
db.docs.aggregate(
    [ 
      { $match : { $and : [qExpiry, qLocation]} },
      { $sort: {"created_at": -1} }.
      { $limit: 50 }.
    ]
);
```

Nevertheless, if any can point out way my first approach did not work, that would be very useful. Simply adding `sort()` to a non-empty query shouldn't suddenly return 0 documents. Just to add, since I still tried for a bit, `.sort({})` return all documents but was not very useful. Everything else failed including `.sort({'_id': 1})`.